# Pre-1960s short story set in endless forest with cloned couples

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to recall an old pre-1960s short story. Some sort of interstellar criminal or villain crashlands into a seemingly endless forest on a remote planet. Blasting a path through the forest with his disintegrator, he finds a house in a clearing inhabited by a man and a woman. Moving on, he finds what appears to be the same clearing, house, and couple - but the couple have a completely different temperament. This repeats until the protagonist goes mad. A short postscript reveals that the houses and couples were set up as some sort of isolated experiments.

I was convinced it was by A.E. van Vogt but a look through his bibliography hasn't turned up anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fritz Leiber not Van Vogt. It's the story [The Enchanted Forest](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52233) published in 1950. I read it so long ago I forget which collection it was, but it's been collected dozens of times.

The criminal is *Elven* and he is the last of a group called the *Wild Ones* but as I recall he has the DNA of his (dead) colleagues in a locket and he plans to resurrect them. His disintegrator is called a *dust gun* and he uses this to blast his way through the forest.

[user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/user14111) points out this has been asked before in [Man crashes on planet and is treated nicely by natives, then nastily by another group. Possibly Isaac Asimov story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195612/man-crashes-on-planet-and-is-treated-nicely-by-natives-then-nastily-by-another) (which he answered!) so if you mark this as accepted we can flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: I wouldn't call Elven a criminal, though he is one from the viewpoint of the tyrannical Evil Empire that uses human beings as experimental animals.